# Remove white line through table

Tags: tables, color

I am new to LaTeX and trying to draw a table. I have followed a couple of guides and found solutions to problems I was having on here but I can't find anything to help me remove the white lines I have running through my table and to the left of the second row.

Please can someone help me?

[image: Image of table with white lines]

```latex
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{multirow, booktabs} 
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} 

\newcolumntype{x}[1]{%
>{\centering\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}%

\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{122, 140, 213}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|x{3cm}|x{3.5cm}|x{3.5cm}| }\hline
\rowcolor{myblue!50}  & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Concentration of Sodium Hydroxide Added /M} \\ \cmidrule{2-3}
\rowcolor{myblue!50} \multirow{-2}{*}{Sample Number} & Drop 1 (left) & Drop 2 (Right)\tabularnewline\hline
 1 & 0.01 M & 1.00 M \tabularnewline\hline
 2 & 0.05 M & 0.10 M \tabularnewline\hline
 3 & 0.10 M & 0.01 M \tabularnewline\hline
 4 & 0.50 M & 0.05 M \tabularnewline\hline
 5 & 1.00 M & 0.50 M \tabularnewline\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `\hhline` rather than `\cmidrule`,  and split the `\multicolumn` in two lines:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{multirow, booktabs, hhline}
\usepackage{array, hhline}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\newcolumntype{x}[1]{%
>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}%

\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{122, 140, 213}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{center}\setlength{\aboverulesep}{0pt}\setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular}{|x{3cm}|x{3.5cm}|x{3.5cm}| }\hline
\rowcolor{myblue!50}[\tabcolsep][\dimexpr\tabcolsep +0.4pt] & \multicolumn{2}{p{\dimexpr7cm + 2\tabcolsep}|}{\centering Concentration of Sodium Hydroxide\newline Added /M} \\[-0.04 pt]
 \hhline{|>{\arrayrulecolor{myblue!50}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|--|}\noalign{\vskip-0.04pt}
\rowcolor{myblue!50}\multirow{-2.}{*}{\cellcolor{myblue!50}Sample Number} & Drop 1 (left) & Drop 2 (Right)\tabularnewline
\hline
 1 & 0.01 M & 1.00 M \\ \hline
 2 & 0.05 M & 0.10 M \\ \hline
 3 & 0.10 M & 0.01 M \\ \hline
 4 & 0.50 M & 0.05 M \\ \hline
 5 & 1.00 M & 0.50 M \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! that has worked!

Answer (score 3):

I would remove not only the white line but also (a) all vertical rules and (b) almost all horizontal lines. Your table will be much more readable as a result of the proposed simplifications.

[image]

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{multirow, booktabs, array}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{122, 140, 213}

\newcolumntype{x}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{x{3cm}x{4cm}x{4cm} }
\rowcolor{myblue!50}  & 
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Concentration of Sodium Hydroxide Added /M} \\ 
\rowcolor{myblue!50} \multirow{-2}{*}{Sample Number} 
& Drop 1 (left) & Drop 2 (right) \\
 1 & 0.01 M & 1.00 M \\
 2 & 0.05 M & 0.10 M \\
 3 & 0.10 M & 0.01 M \\
 4 & 0.50 M & 0.05 M \\
 5 & 1.00 M & 0.50 M \\
\bottomrule % <-- new
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Molarity units provided for each data entry also seem redundant as the header explicitly states them (…/M – "over mole per litre"). Going even more minimalist, one can also get rid of the color as it doesn't really highlight anything: the header is well visible by `\hline`s/`\midrule`s anyway.

Comment: Thank you. I prefer to keep some of the lines in as in some of my larger tables it breaks the data up and I like to be consistent across all tables. Thanks for pointing out I still had M in the table - it was from an earlier iteration before i figured out the \multicolumn feature!

Answer (score 0):

I take it you are using `\cmidrule` because `\cline` gets covered with color.  The good news is that the gaps above and below `\cmidrule` can be set using `\aboverulesep` and `\belowrulesep`.  The bad news is that I haven't figured out how to make temporary changes in the middle of the tabular without getting a "misplaced \noalign" error.

Now the only problem is the gap due to the `\multicolumn` being wider than the normal columns.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{multirow, booktabs} 
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} 

\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{x}[1]{%
>{\centering\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}%

\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{122, 140, 213}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{center}
\aboverulesep=0pt
\belowrulesep=0pt
\begin{tabular}{|x{3cm}|x{3.5cm}|x{3.5cm}| }\hline
\rowcolor{myblue!50}  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Concentration of Sodium Hydroxide Added /M} \\
\cmidrule{2-3}
\rowcolor{myblue!50} \multirow{-2}{*}{Sample Number} & Drop 1 (left) & Drop 2 (Right) \rule{0pt}{\dimexpr \arraystretch\ht\strutbox+2pt}
\tabularnewline\hline
 1 & 0.01 M & 1.00 M \tabularnewline\hline
 2 & 0.05 M & 0.10 M \tabularnewline\hline
 3 & 0.10 M & 0.01 M \tabularnewline\hline
 4 & 0.50 M & 0.05 M \tabularnewline\hline
 5 & 1.00 M & 0.50 M \tabularnewline\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun with TikZ.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\col}[6]{
\path #1  node{#2}
++(-90:1) node{#3}
++(-90:1) node{#4}
++(-90:1) node{#5}
++(-90:1) node{#6};
}% end of \col command
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=4,yscale=.6]
\begin{scope}[shift={(-.5,.5)}]
\draw[teal] 
(0,0) grid (3,-5)
(0,0) rectangle (3,2)
(1,1)--+(0:2) (1,0)--+(90:2) (2,0)--+(90:1);
\end{scope} 
\col{(0,0)}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}
\col{(1,0)}{0.01 M}{0.05 M}{0.10 M}{0.50 M}{1.00 M}
\col{(2,0)}{1.00 M}{0.10 M}{0.01 M}{0.05 M}{0.50 M}
\path
(0,1.5) node{Sample Number}
(1,1)   node{Drop 1 (left)}
(2,1)   node{Drop 2 (right)}
(1.5,2) node{Concentration of Sodium Hydroxide Added /M};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In the above code, if you use

```
\begin{scope}[shift={(-.5,.5)}]
\fill[cyan!30] (0,0) rectangle (3,2);
\draw[cyan] (0,-5)--+(0:3);
\end{scope}
```

then you get

[image]